# How to set url to my application in my maven Surefire Reports?

Tags: maven, report, maven-surefire-plugin

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.learnwell.selnium</groupId>
  <artifactId>demoMercuryTours</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-Version</version>
  <name>mercuryTours</name>
  <description>The app enables a user to register himself after registration user can login to the app and search book flight.</description>
  <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
      </properties>
  <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>3.141.59</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                <version>5.7.0-M1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
                <version>5.7.0-M1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

  </build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

`I am new to maven reporting . I have created a application and now want to test it and for creating testing report I am using maven surefire. How do I give the link to my website in pom.xml for the link in 
project-info.html.
It shows below link on hovering "file:///C:/java143/demotool/target/site/$%7Bproject.url%7D"

How do i set the URL ? to my website, so that whenever someone clicks to the URL it will lead to the website.[image]

Comment: Please show your pom file ...

Comment: Added the pom file. Thanks.